# OSGI+CDI: strange behaviour with system printers detecting

Tags: java, osgi, cdi, weld, pax

I have CDI+OSGI javase application. CDI-Weld,OSGI-felix and pax-cdi. And I have the following code in "CDI-main"

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Foo{

    public void postCreate(@Observes ContainerInitialized event, BundleContext ctx) throws Exception {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        System.out.println("$Number of print services: " + printServices.length);
        for (PrintService printer : printServices)
            System.out.println("$Printer: " + printer.getName()); 
    }
  }
```

When I run this application I will get the following output(although I have printers with right drivers!)

> $Number of print services:0

Notice, the first sign is $;
If I add the following code to bundle activator and start it

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        System.out.println("#Number of print services: " + printServices.length);
        for (PrintService printer : printServices)
            System.out.println("#Printer: " + printer.getName());
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
  }
}
```

Notice, first sign is #.Then all my printers are detected:

```
#Number of print services: 1
#Printer: MF3110
Jun 14, 2015 1:47:34 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer...
....
$Number of print services: 1
$Printer: MF3110
```

How to explain it?

Comment: Probably it's to do with arbitrary start ordering. The # vs $ character is obviously not related, it's purely coincidental.

Answer (score 0):

Is PrintServiceLookup defined in a separate bundle or use code which is from separate OSGI Service? Might it be related to osgi services cardinality?

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet, `PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices` is called in a different LifeCycle Phase than in the second snippet.

In the first example, the Container or Extender might not have satisfied all dependencies for `PrintServiceLookup` when `lookupPrintServices` is called.

In the second example, these dependencies are likely to be satisfied since `lookupPrintServices` is called in a Bundle Activator's `start` method - which is being called by the Container during the STARTING phase. In the STARTING phase, all dependencies of the Bundle are already resolved by the Container.

Hope I could help.